# Can't receive value from input field

Tags: javascript, html

i have problem on sending textbox value from one html page to another html page.
In first page i am sending first name and last name values.and i want to catch this value in textbox on the second page( i.e home.html).but some erroe occurs.

error is :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

how to solve?   please tell me.
 i know this stupid question.but please tell me guys.i don't know javascript.

this is my html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html">
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="ttt.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method="get" action="home.html" name="ff">
 Firstname: <input id="f" type="text" name="firstname1">
 Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is my home.html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html">
 <html>
 <head>

 <script src="ttt.js"></script>
 <script Language="JavaScript">
 var tttt=val();
 document.getElementById('text').value=tttt;
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name="ff">
 <input id="text" class="text" type="text" name="MyValue" value="helloS"/> 
 </form>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is my javascript code(ttt.js)

```
function val(){
  var link=location.href;
  var str=link.split('?');
  var str1=str[1].split('&');
  var str11=str1[0].split('=');
  var str12=str1[1].split('=');
      var temp=str11[1]+" "+str12[1];
  return(temp);
 }
```

Comment: Is there an ID of `tr` on the page?

Comment: There is no "LINK" HTTP method.

Comment: sorry by mistake i wrote tr.but same problem occurs after changing ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your javascript at the end of your html and change `document.getElementById('tr')` to `document.getElementById('text')`. You have no element with id `tr`.

Comment: Put your complete `<script ... </script>` block after the `</html>`.

Comment: but Raidi why this problem occurs? tell me reason.

Comment: In the original version the javascript code was executed before the input element was put on the page, so the code couldn't find it.

Comment: thanks.u cleard my all doubt.because this problem occurs in many program.that's y i am asking.thank u so much Raidi..

Comment: Raidri can u tell me how to store value in sqlite database using html and javascript

Comment: That is beyond this question too and much for a comment. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829818/simplest-jquery-php-ajax-and-sqlite-example) and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

please look at this question and its answers, it is demonstating how to pass value from one html page to another

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470285/how-can-i-pass-values-from-one-html-page-to-another-html-page-using-javascript)

Comment: ya it is demonstating how to pass value from one html page to another.please read my question carefully.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do `getElementById('tr')` when the dom is ready and ensuring that an element with the ID exists.